# When installing mysql in linux, why do we create a mysql group and user?

Tags: mysql

When installing mysql in linux, why do we create a mysql group and user ?
The installation step tells to create a user and to change the ownership of mysql folder to mysql.

Answer (score 4):

Every process under linux runs under specific user privileges. Services (like MySQL) usually need to open ports and access various system resources during startup, so they are required to be started as `root` user. However, it is not safe to have all the processes run under `root` as it is not required for continuous operation of services, thus it is recommended to create a special user, which will be used to run MySQL service. MySQL will only be able to access what special user can, and this is going to be limited to MySQL files on the system.

This is usual practice in linux. If you, however, use you distributions built-in package manager to install MySQL, this will be done for you automatically (in most distributions at least).

Answer (score 0):

When you install MySQL from binaries you need to create mysql group and user.

The **apt** installation of the MySQL package on linux itself creates a mysql user and a group of the same name.

While installing MySQL from binaries It s required for security reasons.

You want to give a permission to user which will use the `MySQL`. And you also give the permission on `datadir` *i.e `/var/lib/mysql` which is default in `ubuntu`*, because your database files are stored there by default.